# Getting around 100 maxresult with AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I am writing a Google App Script that pulls Chromebook device information from gSuite. I need to export it as a CSV to ingest it into a database. I ran into an issue, however. The API 'AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list' is limited to 100 maxResults. I have over 30,000 results.

Here is my test code.

```
function updateDeviceList() {
  var page, pageToken, row, dateTime;

  dateTime = getDateTime();

  deleteAllRows();

  do { 
    page = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list("my_customer", 
      { 
        domain: 'redclayschools.com',
        maxResults: 115,
        orderBy: 'annotatedUser',
        pageToken: pageToken,
        projection: 'full',
        query: 'id:*'
      });

    for (i in page.chromeosdevices) {
      row = getLastRow();
      writeToCell(row, 1, page.chromeosdevices[i].orgUnitPath);
      writeToCell(row, 2, page.chromeosdevices[i].annotatedUser);
      writeToCell(row, 3, page.chromeosdevices[i].annotatedLocation);
      writeToCell(row, 4, page.chromeosdevices[i].annotatedAssetId);
      writeToCell(row, 5, page.chromeosdevices[i].serialNumber);
      writeToCell(row, 6, page.chromeosdevices[i].lastEnrollmentTime);
      writeToCell(row, 7, page.chromeosdevices[i].deviceId);
      writeToCell(row, 8, page.chromeosdevices[i].bootMode);
      writeToCell(row, 9, page.chromeosdevices[i].recentUsers);
      writeToCell(row, 10, page.chromeosdevices[i].macAddress);
      writeToCell(row, 11, page.chromeosdevices[i].lastSync);
      writeToCell(row, 12, page.chromeosdevices[i].osVersion);
      writeToCell(row, 13, page.chromeosdevices[i].platformVersion);
      writeToCell(row, 14, page.chromeosdevices[i].activeTimeRanges);
      writeToCell(row, 15, page.chromeosdevices[i].model);
      writeToCell(row, 16, page.chromeosdevices[i].etag);
      writeToCell(row, 17, page.chromeosdevices[i].firmwareVersion);
      writeToCell(row, 18, page.chromeosdevices[i].status);
      writeToCell(row, 19, page.chromeosdevices[i].ethernetMacAddress);
      writeToCell(row, 20, page.chromeosdevices[i].notes);
      writeToCell(row, 21, dateTime);
    }
  } while (pageToken){

  }
}
```

And my helper functions (this shouldn't matter):

```
function writeToCell(row, column, text) {
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(text);
}
```

Is there a better function to use (I can't seem to find anything), or a way around the 100 maxResult limit? I know the approach with writing directly to the row isn't efficient, this is only test code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits), the API returns a default and a maximum of 100 entries per page for Chrome and mobile devices. [Suggested action](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) is to retry using [exponential back-off](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#backoff). You need to slow down the rate at which you are sending the requests.

Comment: Thank you. I seen that before some reason didn't look at it fully. I implemented that, and the next issue I ran into was moving to the next "page" - that has been implemented as well.. it was fairly simple. Thank you again.